# Form Recognizer issue with multipart file

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Trying to call Form recognizer API for Invoice analyzer and try to pass multipart file with request like below,

```
curl -v -i POST 
"https://xxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/formrecognizer/v2.1/prebuilt/invoice/analyze/formrecognizer/v2.1/prebuilt/invoice/analyze" 
"Content-Type: multipart/form-data" 
-F "form='C:\Users\User\Desktop\Receipt.pdf';type=.pdf" 
-H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: xxxa3fb3553dd81bd1f4c5b1xxx"
```

This giving me error as `"error":{"code":"404","message": "Resource not found"}}`

What i am doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you please share the receipt to check.

Comment: did you mean apim-request-id:  8a17319c-58e3-4048-9327-6a0910a91a13

Answer (score 0):

Currently Azure Form Recognizer Analyze Invoice input document must be of one of the supported content types - 'application/pdf', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png' or 'image/tiff'. Alternatively, use 'application/json' type to specify the Url location of the document to be analyzed. Please check the values you provide for the Azure form Recognizer [resource](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.CognitiveServicesFormRecognizer) and input data [requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/build-training-data-set#custom-model-input-requirements).

404 states: The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI.